# MySQL compound index with a unique subset

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have the following one to one linking table

```
CREATE TABLE `foo_bar` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `foo_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bar_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  …
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  …
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Where `foo_id` and `bar_id` are foreign keys to tables `foo` and `bar` respectively

There is also

- A unique index on `(foo_id, bar_id)` which is used for the foreign key mapping `foo_id` to foo records, and query performance, *and…*
- A unique index on `bar_id` which is used for the foreign key mapping from `bar_id` to bar records

**Note** that this setup does allow non-unique `foo_id`s, as long as they are accompanied by a unique `bar_id`

---

I would now like to enforce uniqueness on `foo_id` alone while retaining the performance benefits of the existing compound index on `(foo_id, bar_id)`

***Is there any way of creating a unique compound index where uniqueness is enforced on a subset of the columns referenced, but allows further columns to be added to the index?***

In this example, this would look like `([foo_id], bar_id)` where the square brackets indicate the unique part of the compound index

I would like to avoid the overhead of a separate index on `(foo_id, bar_id)`

Off the top of my head, I can't think of any algorithmic reason why this wouldn't be possible - as long as the unique subset of columns is at the start of the compound index

**Note** that I'm aware that I could use either `foo_id` or `bar_id` as the primary key for the table, but the application requires a separate ID by which the linking record can be deleted separately without revealing the links

Basically `foo_bar.id` is stored in a client cookie (after being reversibly encrypted), and any personal data is accessible from this ID. The idea is that if a client requests deletion, we delete the `foo_bar` record and remove their data without destroying the anonymised or functional data in `foo` and `bar`

This has the added bonus that, even if the cookie persists anywhere, it will no longer be resolvable to **any** data

Comment: Dont think it is possible in MySQL atleast. But would be a welcome feature.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it right, but when you have a unique index on bar_id already and want to have foo_id to also be unique, there's no need for a separate index on (foo_id, bar_id). The uniqueness of the combination is already guaranteed and I doubt that you will suffer heavy performance losses. MySQL can also merge indexes, if it needs to. And you could also have "duplicate" indexes, the overhead isn't as much as you think. I know, because the developers in my company often make this mistake and/or confuse index and foreign key.

Comment: If you also make `foo_id` unique, what is the need of linking table ? Isn't it mainly used for storing one to many or many to many mappings ?

Comment: *" I know, because the developers in my company often make this mistake and/or confuse index and foreign key"* @fancyPants most likely because MySQL makes a index when making a foreign key also ... *"And you could also have "duplicate" indexes, the overhead isn't as much as you think"* It might cause the optimizer to choose a "wrong" index and getting worse select performance because of that try to avoid making redundant indexes..

Comment: @RaymondNijland  MySql creates index on foreign key also ?

Comment: *" MySql creates index on foreign key also ?"* Yes MySQL can do /does that.. see [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) -> *"index_name represents a foreign key ID. The index_name value is ignored if there is already an explicitly defined index on the child table that can support the foreign key. Otherwise, MySQL implicitly creates a foreign key index that is named according to the following rules: "*

Comment: @fancyPants Not sure a merged index will be super useful in the queries that currently use the index, I will investigate however! While extra indexes aren't a huge performance issue on reads, (unless the optimiser chooses the wrong one - thanks Raymond), they do slow down writes as the relative orders of each record within each index may change

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande It's a one_to_one link, hence the uniques, and exists because we needed a way to destroy the link between the records independently from the link id, without revealing the ids of each linked item

Comment: `foo_id` is `INT`, yet you say it is encrypted??  To squeeze an encrypted value into 32 bits you will have to have a process to deal with dups -- they will happen all to soon.  `MD5()` (or other one-way encryptions) take a lot more bits, but can really be thought of as unique.

Comment: @Arth - (re: merged index) -- Please show us such a query.  We may be able to explain by example why it is not an issue.

Comment: @Arth - "relative orders of each record within each index may change" -- elaborate, please.  It is quite rare for a database application to change the value of an indexed column.

Comment: @Arth - Have you rebutted Ankit's question about the linking table?

Comment: @RickJames Sorry, only just saw these 4 comments.. `foo_bar.id` is stored in the DB as an INT but is reversibly encrypted when stored in the client cookie (I appreciate the confusion).. I'll try and dig out a query re: merged index.. re: relative orders *within* the index, when you write to an indexed column the index has to be checked and potentially reordered, no?

Answer (score 1):

This is a many:many mapping table?

Then get rid if `id`; it is clutter and slows things down.

```
PRIMARY KEY(foo_id, bar_id),
INDEX(bar_id, foo_id)
```

Those and more tips: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

> This has the added bonus that, even if the cookie persists anywhere, it will no longer be resolvable to any data

This implies doing one of these:

- Hang onto all hashes created, but mark some as 'deleted'.
- Otherwise make sure that you never generate the same hash twice.

In either case, you can avoid "resolving" an old cookie to data that is dead or gone.

That somewhat implies the existence of a `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY`) key somewhere for `foo_id` and, separately, `bar_id`.

If those two uniqueness constraints are in the same table and you need a separate `id` for other reasons, then the minimum indexing is:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
UNIQUE(foo_id),
UNIQUE(bar_id)
```

or

```
PRIMARY KEY(foo_id),
UNIQUE(bar_id),
INDEX(id)   -- This is sufficient to keep `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy.
```

There is no need to have any index (plain or `UNIQUE`) on `(foo_id, bar_id)` since the uniqueness constraint on the first is sufficient for both uniqueness of the pair and for efficient lookups.

> foo_bar.id is encrypted and stored in a client cookie ... client requests deletion, we delete the foo_bar record

What kind of encryption?  One-way (md5, shar256, etc)?  Or reversable (aes...)?  If one-way, then you need an index somewhere that maps `CONCAT(foo_id, bar_id)` (or whatever you are doing) to `foobar_id`.

Comment: It's a one to one mapping table, the link is not mandatory, and I want a surrogate ID to be able to reference and delete the link from outside without referencing the ID of either table

Comment: 1:1 makes even less sense.  Why have the table at all?  As for the use of `id`, you probably have the foo_id and bar_id, with which you can do the delete.

Comment: I have added further explanation to the bottom of my question, including why I won't have (and don't want) access to `foo_id` and `bar_id` at the time of the delete

Comment: @Arth - added to my Answer.  Eventually, I may understand what you are doing and be able to better help you.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have reversed my downvote. I'm still a bit confused though.. the foobar_id is encrypted (reversibly) and placed in the cookie.. and the foo and bar records remain after the deletion. I don't want a cookie with either an encrypted foo_id or bar_id hanging around after deletion. We don't do either of the things that you say are implied

Comment: I do like your second suggestion for indexing. Got me thinking.. would switching the PK to bar_id, and adding a unique on foo_id give me the index (foo_id, bar_id) for free? I think MySQL effectively adds the PK on to the end of any index.. but could be wrong!

Comment: @Arth - Correct.

Comment: I see where the confusion about the encryption came from, it's done between the DB and the client cookie.. it's not really relevant to the question. If you add a note to the effect of my last comment, I'll accept the answer - it gets me what I asked for with the same number of indexes